# How to call a page in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using

```
self.location="www.google.com"
```

in javascript. I need to use it in a jquery function. What is the jquery code for self.location

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self.location`

There's no difference - jQuery *is* JavaScript, it's just more of it.  Write a bunch of your own functions to do things and you have a JavaScript library, just like jQuery...but it doesn't remove what was already there.

That being said, `window.location` is probably what you want to avoid confusion in some places (where others use `self`).

Comment: whats the difference between location.href and self.location

Comment: @gov - `self` refers to `window`...but could have been redefined more  locally, some use `self` to refer to `this` inside callbacks, etc.  The `.href` refers to the string property specifically, instead of `location` which is an object, though setting them has the same effect in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert that code in your jQuery function IMO:

```
$("foo").click(function() { 
    window.location="www.google.com"; 
});
```

Using window instead of self will avoid ambiguities if you call self.location where self resolves to something else than the actual window object.

Comment: whats the difference between location.href and self.location